# Xampp Virtual Host Error 500

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, virtualhost

i use xampp on mac os and i want to add virtual host on it

i use this code on apaceh config

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName mvcproject.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mvcproject/public"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mvcproject/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change my host like this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       Masouds-MacBook-Pro.local # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
127.0.0.1       mvcproject.local
```

but i have this error

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

> Error 500
>
> mvcproject.local
>     Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.2.5 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

How can i solve this problem?!
thanks.!

Comment: Are you sure that the CGI script actually is not the problem?

Comment: what is the CGI Script!?

Comment: I assumed you had a CGI script becaue you added `ExecCGI` and that is mentioned in the error message

Comment: How can i Solve this Problem!?

Answer (score 0):

These are some point to help in create virtual host on mac

1. `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` in this file uncomment the 
   include line

   `Virtual hosts
   Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. Add your site into vhosts file 
   `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
   **My custom host**

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourusername/path/to/your/site"
    <Directory "/Users/yourusername/path/to/your/site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Edit your host file

```html
     sudo nano /etc/hosts
    #Add the following line
    127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

4. Restart your XAMPP